# How to pass class of List object in restful web api

Tags: c#, json, rest, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass list object of class in restful web api. But i am receiving `null` value in web api.
Below is my code in Web API.

```
    Public class RequestDto
    {
      private string _clientId;
      public string ClientId
      {
          get { return _clientId; }
          set { _clientId= value; }
      }
      private List<DeliveryDocument> _deliveryDocumentInfo;
      public List<DeliveryDocument> DeliveryDocumentInfo
      {
          get { return _deliveryDocumentInfo; }
          set { _deliveryDocumentInfo = value; }
      }   
    }        
    public class DeliveryDocument
    {
       public string DocumentName { get; set; }
       public string DocumentURL { get; set; }
    }

public HttpResponseMessage PostSaveManifest([FromBody] RequestDto manifestRequest)
        {
//here i am receiving null value in list parameter
}
```

Below code for calling web api.

```
var values = new JObject();
values.Add("ClientId", "23824");

var DeliveryDocumentInfo = new List<DeliveryDocument>();
DeliveryDocumentInfo.Add(new DeliveryDocument { DocumentName = "Document Name", DocumentURL = "D:/Documnet/test.png" });
var serOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DeliveryDocumentInfo);
values.Add("DeliveryDocumentInfo", serOut);

HttpContent content = new StringContent(values.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var responsesss = client.PostAsync(Constants.URLValue + "/api/Manifest", content).Result;
```

Comment: did you try to create RequestDto and not the jobject like you did?

Comment: No, i am not doing.. but i will try..

Comment: @OrenHaliva its working with RequestDto object. thanks

Comment: It's because you are passing the collection into the `JObject` as a string when you serialize it. the serOut will look something like `"DeliveryDocumentInfo" : "[{}]"`. That is why the collection is null when parsed. But you have already found a work around so it's all good. Just wanted to let you know where the error was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create object of RequestDto in Web API. As per **OrenHaliva** comments.

```
var manifest = new RequestDto();
manifest.ClientId = "23824";

var DeliveryDocumentInfo = new List<DeliveryDocument>();

DeliveryDocumentInfo.Add(new DeliveryDocument { DocumentName = "Document Name", DocumentURL = "D:/Documnet/test.png" });

manifest.DeliveryDocumentInfo = DeliveryDocumentInfo;

var serOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(manifest);
HttpContent content = new StringContent(serOut, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var responsesss = client.PostAsync(Constants.URLValue + "/api/Manifest", content).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are sending cannot serialize into the RequestDto type. "values" is a list, which is in your Dto object but your api is expecting the dto object, not just the list inside of it.

Comment: Not like that... I only pass the single RequestDto object, but under the RequestDto object i pass list of document.