# Angularjs join two objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have two objects:

```
obj1 = { 'id1': 1, 'name1': 'anyone1', 'birth1': 22, 'year1': 1993 };

obj2 = { 'id2': 1, 'name2': 'anyone', 'birth2': 22, 'year2': 1993 };
```

And I would like to create a Array like:

```
ARRAY = {

          obj1 = { 
                    'id1': 1, 'name1': 'anyone1', 'birth1': 22, 'year1': 1993                  
                 },   

        obj2 = { 
                  'id2': 1, 'name2': 'anyone', 'birth2': 22, 'year2': 1993 
                }

          }
```

I would like to call it like '`ARRAY.obj1.id1`'

How can I do this?

Comment: This is very confusing... Why do you want to name a object "ARRAY"? Are you trying to intentionally mislead other developers? :D

Comment: @Canastro, see associative arrays in PHP for example. They are used there pretty much like we use Object literals in JS. But I agree, names sometimes matter.

Comment: Yes in php we have associative arrays, in javascript I prefer to call it `map`. I'm very fond on using maps in javascript, I'm in love with `normalizr`.

Comment: I did it because of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216605/pass-multiple-params-from-angular-to-web-api-2?noredirect=1#comment71595040_42216605), I created a CompositeObject like [this other asnwer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874490/pass-multiple-complex-objects-to-a-post-put-web-api-method#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create a new `object` with two `keys`:

```js
obj1 = { 'id1': 1, 'name1': 'anyone1', 'birth1': 22, 'year1': 1993 };

obj2 = { 'id2': 1, 'name2': 'anyone', 'birth2': 22, 'year2': 1993 };
var obj={};
obj["obj1"]=obj1;
obj["obj2"]=obj2;
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.obj1.id1);
```

Comment: Really should not name that object Array.

Comment: I don't know what issue this addresses; if it satisfies OP, great, but then OP's problem is that he doesn't know how objects work in js.  You technically don't even need the square brackets and quotes to make an object do this.  But let's say we come up with an element called `obj["hasOwnProperty"]`.  That's why we have the `Map` class in ES6, which is what OP should be using instead.

Comment: @kfm, don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Another example using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
obj1 = { 'id1': 1, 'name1': 'anyone1', 'birth1': 22, 'year1': 1993 };
obj2 = { 'id2': 1, 'name2': 'anyone', 'birth2': 22, 'year2': 1993 };
var obj3 = Object.assign({}, { obj1: obj1 }, { obj2: obj2} );
console.log(obj3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, since it was an angular question, you can also use the [`angular.extend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) function:

```js
var obj1 = { 'id1': 1, 'name1': 'anyone1', 'birth1': 22, 'year1': 1993 };
var obj2 = { 'id2': 1, 'name2': 'anyone', 'birth2': 22, 'year2': 1993 };
var obj3 = angular.extend({}, { obj1: obj1, obj2: obj2 } );
console.log(obj3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var myNamedStuff = new Map;
myNamedStuff.set("obj1", obj1);
```

etc.

What you're asking for is a `Map`.  We used plain objects as maps before ES6, but we got all sorts of security risks and exceptions related to name clashes, especially when vendor-specific properties show up in `Object.prototype`.  ES6 introduces the `Map` so that we never do that again and instead have a guaranteed clean name space like we really wanted.