# jQuery GET with parameters always null on server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, http-get

I don't know what I'm missing.

Everything works when passing complex custom objects, but when I try to pass a simple int or string I get `null`

Here is the ajax call on client side:

```
var id = 1;
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/api/APICalls/MethodName",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: JSON.stringify(id), // or JSON.stringify({id: id}) or just id
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
       console.log(data);
   },
   error: function (data) {
       alert(data.responseText);
   }
});
```

On server side the method is as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public void MethodName([FromBody] string id)
{
    // Do something with id... Doesn't matter... It is `null`!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `null` value for `id` parameter is `[FromBody]`. Technically when you send `GET` request to the server with `jQuery` the data is presented in the query parameters and not in the request body.

What you need to do on backend side is just to remove `[FromBody]` as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public void MethodName(string id)
{
    // Now you should be able to access the value of id
}
```

Sending data from client side as the following:

```
var id = 1;

$.ajax({
   url: '/api/APICalls/MethodName',
   type: 'GET',
   data: {id: id},
   success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   },
   error: function (err) {
      console.error(err);
   }
});
```

From the documentation for [`[FormBody]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) you can read the following:

> To force Web API to read a simple type from the request body, add the `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter.

Your data was presented in the query string, checking the network tab in Chrome:

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks. Just one more clarification. I should define the `dataType` and `contentType` only on `post` calls? What if I want to use an object as parameter for `GET`. Something like `object = {param1: 1, param2: 2}`. Then it will be `data: {paramObject: object}` and on server side `MethodName(ObjectType paramObject)`. Is that correct?

Comment: I would send the data with `POST` request in that case and define the types. If you are interested further please find this answer, this explains more about complex objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874490/pass-multiple-complex-objects-to-a-post-put-web-api-method/24876680#24876680